# Laravel 5.5 -- Separate table for authenticated users and guest users

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

My search for the topic *Laravel 5.5 -- Separate table for authenticated users and guest users* has resulted in separate URL for authenticated and guest users. However, I have a table of which, few fields are for all users and remaining are for only authenticated users. Should I split the table?

I want to split the table because the function below returns all the columns. In the view, I only choose the specific fields to be displayed. If someone makes a GET request without a browser, won't it return all columns irrespective of user type.

```
public function show(Balancesheet $Balancesheet) { 
    return view('Balancesheets.show', compact('Balancesheet')); 
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of separating the tables?

Comment: It is because , the function below returns all the columns. In view I only chooses the specific fields to be displayed. If someone makes a get requests without browser, won't it return the all columns irrespective of user type.
    public function show(Balancesheet $Balancesheet)
    {
        return view('Balancesheets.show',compact('Balancesheet'));
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following code more useful .

```
public function show(Balancesheet $Balancesheet) { 

if(\Auth::user()) {
    $Balancesheet = Balancesheet->take(10)->select('name', 'slug')->get(); 
} else {
    $Balancesheet = Balancesheet->select('cashflow', 'district')->take(10)->select('name', 'slug')->get(); 
}

    return view('Balancesheets.show',compact('Balancesheet')); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a specific column, you can use 'pluck()' method, which allows you to select a specific column. If your Laravel version older then 5.3 rename pluck as `lists`:

```
if(\Auth::user())  {
    User::pluck('user_column')->all();
} else  {
    User::pluck('guest_column')->all();
}
```

If you need to more than one column you can choose them within `get()` method:

```
if(\Auth::user()) {
    query->get(['guest','columns']);
} else  {
    query->get(['user','columns']);
}
```